# Can't set textColor of UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uicolor

I'm currently working on a dynamic form that's originated from UITableViewCells Xibs.

```
if disabled {
    self.passTitleLabel.textColor = UIColor(named: "Dark Blue")
    self.textField.textColor = UIColor(named: "Dark Blue")
} else {
    self.passTitleLabel.textColor = UIColor(named: "Light Blue")
    self.textField.textColor = .white
}
```

The UILabel (`passTitleLabel`) keeps the color set on the Storyboard file and doesn't change as expected. The UILabel is enabled and not highlighted but it is still preserving the color on the storyboard.

All the colors are working in other classes (they're on `Assets.xcassets`). The Label is properly set with an IBOutlet.

Comment: Where is this code that you posted?

Comment: Split your lines into 2. For example, `let color = UIColor(named: "Dark Blue")` then `self.passTitleLabel.textColor = color`. Make sure `color` isn't `nil` at runtime.

Comment: @rmaddy the code is being called when the update of the cell is called, just like the other fields of the form. I did split into 2 lines, still the same thing. Thanks :)

Comment: My guess is that `passTitleLabel` outlet is connected to a different label than you think.

Comment: When you split the lines, was `color` nil or not?

Comment: set the color to nil, and verify whether it's becoming black. If its black, the outlet is working fine.

Comment: @Super_Simon That's probably because `darkBlue` and `lightBlue` are not built into `UIColor` class AFAIK

Comment: @ghearly Just out of curiosity, did you try using the `UIColor.init(red: blue: green: )` to see if that works? Also, are you sure this method is being called on the main thread?

Answer (score 9):

Ran into the same issue, took me a while but finally found an answer. Looks like your UITableViewCell or UICollectionViewCell is running in a background thread, UI related operations need to be done in the main thread or it can lead to these type of problems.

```
if disabled {
   DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.passTitleLabel.textColor = UIColor(named: "Dark Blue")
      self.textField.textColor = UIColor(named: "Dark Blue")
   }
} else {
   DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.passTitleLabel.textColor = UIColor(named: "Light Blue")
      self.textField.textColor = .white
   }
}
```